# Fit multiple Objects in one Row with CSVHelper in C#

Tags: c#, csvhelper, csvhelper.excel.core

i am trying to write two different Objects in one row with the C# library CSVHelper.
It should look something like this:

```
obj1           obj2
-----------|------------
record1       record1
record2       record2
```

When register the class maps for these two objects and then call WriteRecords(List) and WriteRecords(List) these objects are written but they are not in the same row. Instead the records of obj2 are written in the rows following the records of obj1.
It looks like this:

```
obj1
----------
record1
record2

obj2
----------
record1
record2
```

Program.cs:

```
string fileReadDirectory =
    Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory), "Stuecklisten");
string fileWriteDirectory =
    Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory), "Stueckliste.csv");
List<string> files = Directory.GetFiles(fileReadDirectory).ToList();
List<Part> parts = new List<Part>();
List<PartsPerList> partsPerLists = new List<PartsPerList>();
foreach (string file in files)
{
    //Reads records from Excel File
    CsvReader reader = new CsvReader(new ExcelParser(file));
    reader.Context.RegisterClassMap<ExcelSheetMap>();
    IEnumerable<Part>? excelRecords = reader.GetRecords<Part>();
    
    foreach (var record in excelRecords)
    {
        PartsPerList partsPerList = new PartsPerList();
        partsPerList.Listname = file;
        if (parts.Any(p => p.ManufacturerNr == record.ManufacturerNr))
        {
            Part part = parts.SingleOrDefault(p => p.ManufacturerNr == record.ManufacturerNr) ?? new Part();
            part.TotalQuantity += record.TotalQuantity;
        }
        else
        {
            parts.Add(record);
        }
        partsPerLists.Add(partsPerList);
    }
}
using (var stream = File.Open(fileWriteDirectory, FileMode.Create))
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(stream))
using (var writer = new CsvWriter(streamWriter,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
    writer.Context.RegisterClassMap<ExcelSheetMap>();
    writer.Context.RegisterClassMap<ManufacturerPartsMap>();
    writer.WriteHeader(typeof(Part));
    writer.WriteRecords(parts);
    writer.WriteHeader(typeof(PartsPerList));
    writer.WriteRecords(partsPerLists);
}
```

Part.cs:

```
public class Part
{
    // public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public int TotalQuantity { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Designator { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Case { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Value { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Tolerance { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Remark { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string PartNumber { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Manufacturer { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string ManufacturerNr { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string RoHS { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Nachweis { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    
}
```

Part Classmap:

```
public sealed class ExcelSheetMap : ClassMap<Part>
{
    public ExcelSheetMap()
    {
        // Map(m => m.Quantity).Name("Qty per pcs");
        Map(m => m.TotalQuantity).Index(0);
        Map(m => m.Description).Name("description");
        Map(m => m.Designator).Name("designator");
        Map(m => m.Case).Name("case");
        Map(m => m.Value).Name("value");
        Map(m => m.Tolerance).Name("tolerance");
        Map(m => m.Remark).Name("remark");
        Map(m => m.PartNumber).Name("partnumber");
        Map(m => m.Manufacturer).Name("manufacturer");
        Map(m => m.ManufacturerNr).Name("Manufactorer number");
        Map(m => m.RoHS).Name("RoHS");
        Map(m => m.Nachweis).Name("Nachweis");
    }
}
```

PartsPerList.cs:

```
public class PartsPerList
{
    public string Listname { get; set; } = string.Empty;
   
}
```

ManufacturersPartsMap.cs:

```
public class ManufacturerPartsMap : ClassMap<PartsPerList>
{
    public ManufacturerPartsMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.Listname).Name("test").Optional();
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is unclear. A CSV file is a text file with simple values separated by commas. Not objects. Neither of the text examples you posted is a CSV. Any application that expects to load a CSV would fail

Comment: What are you trying to do? Post *actual* samples of the source and desired data. If you want to merge two different lists, do that *before* trying to save to a text file

Comment: The code you posted doesn't help. A CSV is a very specific thing. Simple but specific. What you posted isn't a CSV. The code you posted doesn't change that fact

Comment: And Excel is most certainly not a text file, much less CSV. It's a ZIP package containing well-defined XML files according to the Open XML Schema. There's *NO WAY* you can create a ZIP file with a StreamWriter

Comment: If you want to create an Excel file you'll find a *lot* of relevant SO questions. You can use libraries like EPPlus or ClosedXML to create real Excel files with just 1 line of code, 4-5 with the necessary boilerplate. Eg in Epplus, to fill a sheet with data from a list all you need to do is `worksheet.Cells.LoadFromCollection(thatCollection);`.

Comment: Well i can read the records of an excel file and then write it to a CSV file with the above code. In CSV Helper every row is an individual object and everything separated by ; is a property of that object. Now I want to read data form an excel file and after processing I want to write the results to a CSV file. My problem is that I have two objects that I want to write in the same row. My final goal is to have a variable number of additional properties depending on the number of excel files read. Btw I installed the package CsvHelper.Excel.Core so its possible to read and write Excel files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write two different objects in one row with `CSVHelper`, you can loop through the records and write them line by line.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var fooRecords = new List<Foo>
    {
        new Foo { Id = 1, Name = "one" },
        new Foo { Id = 2, Name = "two" },
    };

    var barRecords = new List<Bar>
    {
        new Bar { Id = 3, Description = "The first one" },
        new Bar { Id = 4, Description = "The secord one" },
    };

    //using (var writer = new StreamWriter("path\\to\\file.csv"))
    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(Console.Out, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        csv.WriteHeader<Foo>();
        csv.WriteHeader<Bar>();
        csv.NextRecord();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < fooRecords.Count; i++)
        {
            csv.WriteRecord(fooRecords[i]);
            csv.WriteRecord(barRecords[i]);
            csv.NextRecord();
        }
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    [Name("FooId")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    [Name("BarId")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```